# Laravel Date Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, eloquent

I have one table vehicles_unavailabilities with following structure:

[image: vehicle_unavailabilities_table]

The from_date and to_date are the dates that the vehicle has been booked and shouldn't show in the search result for the given dates.

In the search form field, there are two inputs, from_date and to_date. I need to get the data if the vehicle is available or not. I've tried following eloquent query. But i don't this is working. Can anyone help in building the query to meet this requirement?

```
public function getUnavailability($vehicle_id,$from,$to)
    {
        $vehicles = VehicleUnavailability::where('vehicle_id',$vehicle_id)->where('status',1)
                                            ->whereBetween('from_date', [$from, $to])
                                            ->orwhereBetween('to_date', [$from, $to])->get();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you try with `whereDateBetween` instead of `whereBetween`

Comment: Sometimes these sorts of tables are called 'bookings'

Comment: And typically, Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and end after Event B starts.

Comment: @Strawberry, Thanks for your response. since there could be case of unavailability beyong booking, i had to create this table. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: @Espresso. I have actually tried that as well. This query actuallu check the from_date and to_date from the database only, not the interval between them.

Comment: Other sorts of 'unavailabilites', are normally stored in a separate table, i.e., 'availability'.

Comment: So you want the from and to inputs be between from_date and to_date. right?

Comment: @MHIdea the range from the from and to inputs between from_date and to_date. Yes right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**where** compares two dates and is enough.

```php
    $VehicleUnavailability= Car::where('status', 1)
        ->where('vehicle_id',$vehicle_id)
        ->where('from_date', '<=', $from)
        ->where('to_date', '>=', $to)->get();
```